# How to create series of pandas dataframe by iteration

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I want to create df_2008 to df_2014 from an original df by iteration. 
df has columns names '2008' to '2014' and I want to seperate them into different dfs.

I tried

```
for i in range(2008, 2015):
    'df_'+str(i)=df[str(i)]
```

Which won't work.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Comment: Do you want to create variables df_2008 to df_2014 ?

Comment: I don't have experience with pandas but could you change the = to +?

Comment: No, I want to create dataframes names df_2008 to df_2014 from original dataframe, df. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create variables by string, you can use - `globals()` function , which returns the dictionary of global namespace, and then create a new element in that dictionary for your variable and set the value to the value you want.

Also , you can directly call - `pandas.DataFrame(Series)` - and this would create the DataFrame for you, from the series.

Example -

```
import pandas as pd
gbl = globals()
for i in range(2008, 2015):
    gbl['df_'+str(i)] = pd.DataFrame(df[str(i)])
```

Example code -

```
In [8]: d = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]], columns = ['A','B','C','D'])

In [9]: d
Out[9]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  4
1  5  6  7  8

In [10]: gbl = globals()

In [11]: gbl['e'] = pd.DataFrame(d['A'])

In [12]: e
Out[12]: 
   A
0  1
1  5
```

Comment: Would above you to accept answers when grey help you ( by clicking on tick mark ) on the left , helps the community a lot.